# How to save HTML5 canvas images as attachments and present them in RichText fields in the Basic Notes Client with XPages

Tags: html, canvas, xpages, xpages-ssjs

have a backward compatibility issue of presenting the results of an HTML5 Canvas control (based on [Dec's blog post](http://www.qtzar.com/5g5nmpbf67sw/) and the [OpenNTF Project](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Signature%20Capture%20Control))

I have built logic to create a PNG attachment using MIME, but it is saved as MIME and the rich-text field only shows it as an attachment. The `session.setConvertMime(true)` is being ignored.

Client side submission code:

```
var sig = x$("#{id:canvasOutput1}").val();
// Verify that they have signed the canvas area.
if(sig.length == 0) {
    alert("Please sign above before submitting.");
    return false;
}
// Get the image data and but it into a hidden field for submissio
var wcanvas = document.getElementById("#{id:canvasArea1}");
var dataURL = wcanvas.toDataURL();
x$("#{id:imgBase64EB1}").val(dataURL);

return true;
```

Server side SSJS submission code:

```
var img64 = sigdoc.getItemValue("imgBase64").get(0);
try {
    
    var dt:Date = new Date();
    session.setConvertMime(true);
    
    var tdoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
    tdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "TestSignature");
    tdoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Created: " + dt.toLocaleString());
    tdoc.replaceItemValue("imgBase64", sigdoc.getItemValue("imgBase64"));
    tdoc.replaceItemValue("signature", sigdoc.getItemValue("signature"));
    
    // Convert the canvas image to a mime element in the document
    importPackage(com.healthspace.tools);
    var cis = new CanvasImageSaver();
    tdoc = cis.convertStream(tdoc, img64, "Signature1");
    
    if (tdoc != null) {
        session.setConvertMime(true);
        tdoc.save();
        
        context.redirectToPage("test_signature.xsp");
    }
} catch(e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The convertStream method in the package is:

```
    public Document convertStream(Document doc, String imgBase64, String fldname) {
        Session ns = Factory.getSession()
        Stream stream = null;
        MIMEEntity body = null;
        MIMEEntity imgMe = null;
        try {
            //remove the header stuff...
            String buffer = imgBase64.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            ns.setConvertMime(true);
            body = doc.createMIMEEntity(fldname);
            imgMe = body.createChildEntity();

            stream = ns.createStream();
            stream.writeText(buffer);
            imgMe.setContentFromText(stream, "image/png", MIMEEntity.ENC_BASE64);
            stream.truncate();
            stream.close();

            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The issues are that the rendered richtext field has a PNG attachment in it but does not present well. How can this be converted to an in-line image so the Notes and XPages versions of the app work the same?

(Note: I am using the openntf domino api and Twitter bootstrap throughout this app.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from your convertStream function is a MIME document with ONE mime part of type image/png: your attachment. What is missing is a second part of type text/html that has an img tag and eventually some additional text. Something along the line:

```
htmlMe = body.createChildEntity();
textStream = ns.createStream();
textStream.writeText("<html><body>");
textStream.writeText("<img src=\"..this is the tricky part..\" />");
textStream.writeText("</body></html>");
htmlMe.setContentFromText(textStream,"text/html",MIMEEntity.ENC_[whatever]);
```

The tricky part is the URL, that needs to point to your attachment. Actually not too tricky. It takes the format:

```
<img src="cid:_2_DD6FBEF0DD6FBD9C000F014148257D17" />
```

and cid refers to a header that you have to add to your image attachment:

```
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
 Content-ID: <_2_DD6FBEF0DD6FBD9C000F014148257D17>
```

I picked that from a sample message I my understanding is, that you do need the < > around the content id.

Comment: This works but now I have the attachment showing as well as the embedded signature using the HTML... Need to determine how to hide the attachment...

Comment: I found this technique to compute the image ID (since i do not necessarily have a UNID at this point in time) {String imgid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();}

Comment: You need to define the image as multipart/related. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Related

Comment: You know me and I am pretty dense, but I have NO IDEA how to define the image as multipart/related. I've tried making the parent MIMEEntity multipart/realted, the image MIMEEntity, the HTML MIMEEntity and nothing works. I must be missing something but can find no concise explanation of what.

Comment: I'll look for a sample for you. Somewhen in the weekend

Comment: Found a simple approach. Instead of building the attachement MIME part, simply define the image in the HTML Mime part using: textStream.writeText("<img src=\"" + imgBase64 + "\" />");

Comment: That might work. You need to however test it carefully since different browser versions have different size limits for how much base64 data they can take in a src attribute